# Why bootloaders can only accept 16bit assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, x86-16, bootloader

When writing my own MBR, I need to tell nasm to use `16bit` assembly, and I wonder why in 2020 we must use `16bit` assembly in order to write a bootloader.

Why can't we develop bootloaders with modern x64 assembly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can.

If you don't want to deal with legacy BIOS 16-bit inconveniences, then write a UEFI bootloader instead of a legacy MBR.  A UEFI bootloader is a 32-bit or x86-64 "application" loaded by the firmware in a very different environment than an MBR, from a filesystem rather than a specific place on the disk, meaning less futzing around with embedding a tiny amount of code (512 bytes) into a special place on the disk.

---

Mainstream PCs have booted with UEFI for over a decade; having the firmware put the CPU into real mode and set up legacy BIOS call handlers is a backwards compat feature to maintain compatibility with MBR booting, because that format has no room for metadata to tell the system what mode you want to boot in.

Note that having the CPU in 64-bit long mode requires paging to be enabled, so just modifying MBR booting to have the CPU in 64-bit mode on entry to the MBR wouldn't work well.  You'd need a bunch of new standardization.  A lot of the real-mode BIOS API is obsolete stuff that hasn't kept up with modern PCs, like disk access based on CHS not linear offsets, no easy support for graphics + mouse, and no filesystem access.  So it was time for a total revamp.  Not to mention the horrors   of barely compliant BIOSes that happen to work with a Windows bootloader but differ from each other in various random ways, like how they set CS:IP for the same linear address, or other segment registers.

The industry ended up going with EFI / UEFI as a total replacement for legacy IBM-PC BIOS style booting.  https://wiki.osdev.org/UEFI

Comment: "hasn't kept up with modern PCs, like disk access based on CHS not linear offsets" - To be fair, LBA extensions to interrupt 13h services have been around since before UEFI.

Comment: @ecm: Fair point. But can you count on them being available on every system that could boot your MBR?  If not, then it's still potentially problematic or inconvenient.  Perhaps a better example would have been graphics + mouse, *filesystem* access (rather than raw disk sectors) so you can update a bootloader without re-embedding it into sectors before a real partition, maybe USB / removable devices including removable storage.  Maybe optical disks?  Although the relevance of optical disks is lower these days.  Also disk detection order can be problematic.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I have a multi-boot system, that uses MBR - Win XP, Win XP X64, Win 7 Pro 64 bit, Win 10 Pro 64 bit. EFI/UEFI is nice, but it isn't needed for any current version of Windows (maybe server versions need it?).

Comment: @rcgldr: I over-simplified of course.  Most (all?) modern PCs *can* be configured to boot in legacy BIOS mode.  But out of the box, mainstream PCs are *not* configured that way, so boots (across all PCs in the world that boot in any given day) go from hardware reset to OS fully running without involving an MBR bootloader.  Unless there are a *lot* more old PCs around than I expect, in which case I mean "modern" PCs, made in years when UEFI was old enough to be stable and used as a default.  The fact that you *can* still boot modern OSes from a legacy MBR is irrelevant to my point.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Does Win XP / Win XP X64 support EFI/UEFI boot? What about  a multi-boot Win 7  / Win 10 setup or just a Win 7 setup? I don't have a Win 7 system that isn't multi-boot, so I don't know if Win 7 defaults to a legacy text mode screen boot. I only get the Win PE boot if I make Win 10 the default boot OS.

Comment: @rcgldr: IDK whether WinXP supports UEFI, and I don't see how that's relevant.  By the time UEFI support was stable and common, new computers were usually sold with Win7 or Win10, both of which I think can use UEFI + secure boot.  But I don't really know or care about win7; I use UEFI to boot GNU/Linux on my desktop.  My parents and brother have Win10 PCs that boot via UEFI, the mainstream config.  And this question is about writing a bootloader from scratch, not compatibility with existing old OSes.